# SharePoint - document library items to list

Tags: list, sharepoint, document, web-parts, foundation

What is best way to do this?

I want to read all document library items to list and create direct link those documents. Or is it easier read documents to webpart, example to Listbox/DataGrid?

Example:

**Document library**

- MyDocument.doc

**MyList**

- Link to MyDocument.doc file

Sorry about this stupid question, but I try to create my first webpart.
If you can help me in the right direction... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn how to get documents from a document libraries(or get items from a list) and you can get the url of the document items. So, you will be able to creating your web part as you want. If you're going to using server code(C#) you should learn to using sharepoint object model. Otherwise, sharepoint client object model. Here is a link for your reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx